# Django ModelForm widgets and labels

Tags: python, django, modelform

When I have a regular ModelForm field, setting up its widgets and/or labels will look like this:

```
class MyModelForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field_x', 'field_y']
        widgets = {
            'field_x': Forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myclass', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'field_y': Forms.Select(attrs{'class': 'myclass'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'field_x': 'Input your X value here',
            'field_y': 'Select your Y value here',
        }
```

And it's all ok so far. But when it comes about more "complicated" fields, widgets will ignore its attrs... and it's getting me sick.

Example:

```
class MyComplicatedModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_z = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AnyClass.objects.all(), empty_label=None, required=True, to_field_name='id')

    class Meta:
        model = MyComplicatedModel
        fields = ['field_z']
        widgets = {
                'field_z': Forms.ModelChoiceField(attrs={'class': 'myclass'}),
        }
        labels = {
                'field_z': 'Select your Z value here',
        }
```

And it will work ok but it will ignore its `widgets = {}` and `labels = {}`, it will have a default class and the label will be the name of the field ("field_z").
How can I manage widgets and labels when it is not a "regular" field like this last one?

Comment: In the second snippet are those `fields`/`widgets`/`labels` not within a Meta class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry it was a mistake typing my example. I edited and fixed it. How can I handle the field appearance if I can't use widgets?

Comment: You were using ModelChoiceField in widget widgets. and that doesn't work. use a widget like selectMultiple instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`widgets` and `labels` are for overriding the relevant attributes of fields created automatically from the model. But in the case of `field_z`, it's not being created automatically; you've specifically supplied a definition. So you need to set the relevant attributes directly in that definition:

```
class MyComplicatedModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_z = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=AnyClass.objects.all(),
        empty_label=None,
        required=True,
        to_field_name='id',
        label='Select your Z value here',
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'myclass'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyComplicatedModel
        fields = ['field_z']
```

Note that ModelChoiceField is a field, not a widget, so wouldn't work in `widgets` anyway - the relevant widget is [`SelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectMultiple).